# Changing variable in a supremum integral inequality

Tags: general-topology, inequality, normed-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

So I'm trying to prove that this operator
$$
T_n(f)=\int_0^t \cfrac{(t-x)^n}{(n-1)!}f(x)dx
$$ is continuous and then calculate its operator norm, provided that

- the operator is a map $E\to E$ with $E=C([0,1],\Bbb R)$, and
- the norm considered on $E$ is the infinite norm.

To prove the continuity I tried to find a $M>0$ such that $\|T_n(f)\|_\infty  < M\|f\|_\infty $.

After developing  I got to this inequality :
$$
||T_n(f)||_\infty < \int_0^t\sup_{t\in[0,1]} \cfrac{(t-x)^n}{(n-1)!}f(x)dx
$$

What I'm trying to do is change the $t$ of the supremum to $x$ so that I could sort the $f(x)$ out and integrate the quantity $\cfrac{(t-x)^n}{(n-1)!}$ to get the required $M$ for the continuity.

Any tips on how to proceed?

Comment: How exactly do you get the inequality? There seems to be something wrong there...

Comment: @supinf I just used the property $\sup \int \leq \int \sup$

Comment: you cannot use the same variable $t$ for both the integral bounds and the $\sup$. Also, it is $\leq$ and not $<$, as you said.

Comment: @supinf I don't get the remark, why can't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that
$$
 \int_0^t \cfrac{(t-x)^n}{(n-1)!} dx= \cfrac{t^n}{n!} \,.
$$
Therefore

$$\|T_n(f)\|_\infty  \le \cfrac{1}{n!} \|f\|_\infty \,,\quad (*)$$
with equality for $f \equiv 1$, so the operator norm of $T_n$ is $\cfrac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I don't get what you mean by this "with equality for f≡1, so the operator norm of Tn is 1n!.", how did you deduce that the operator norm is thus equal to $\frac{1}{n!}$? Can you refer me to the theorem? I remember coming across something similar but couldn't find it.

Comment: What I meant is that if you set $f=1$ identically, then both sides of $(*)$ are equal. That, together with $(*)$, gives you the operator norm of $T_n$ by the definition.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm